# Simple bash script using "set" command

Tags: bash

I am supposed to make a script that prints all sizes and file-names in the current directory, ordered by size, using the "set" command.

```
#!/bin/bash

touch /tmp/unsorted

IFS='@'
export IFS

ls -l | tr -s " " "@" | sed '1d' > /tmp/tempLS

while read line
do
    ##set probably goes here##
    echo $5 $9 >> /tmp/unsorted
done < /tmp/tempLS

sort -n /tmp/unsorted
rm -rf /tmp/unsorted
```

By logic, this is the script that should work, but it produces only blank lines.
After discussion with my classmates, we think that the "set" command must go first in the while loop. The problem is that we cant understand what the "set" command does, and how to use it. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: what did you expect in `$5` to be and what are you trying to do?

Comment: $5 is the size and $9 is the file-name

Comment: Be aware that if a filename has a space, it will not be entirely contained in `$9`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ls -l | while read line; do
  set - $line
  echo $5 $9
done | sort -n
```

or simply

```
ls -l | awk '{print $5, $9}' | sort -n
```

Comment: It works! both with `set -` , and with `set --` . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Set manipulates shell variables. This allows you to adjust your current environment for specific situations, for example, to adjust current globbing rules.

Sometimes it is necessary to adjust the environment in a script, so that it will have an option set correctly later on. Since the script runs in a subshell, the options you adjust will have no effect outside of the script.

[This link](http://ss64.com/bash/) has a vast amount of info on the various commands and options available.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, i have read this page when i was googling "set". But i can't think of any variables that i can manipulate.

Comment: @alf the list of variables is under the syntax link at the top of the page. Or you can just check the bash man page in your terminal for a more complete listing.